# What is the most efficient way of removing a single element from a large array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

We have a website written in Vue.js that retrieves a number of objects from an API and stores them as an array. The user is presented with this data in a data table, and has the opportunity to delete a single item at a time. The amount of objects in this array is usually in the 700-2000 range, but can theoretically be anywhere between 0 and tens of thousands (highly unlikely)

My question then is: **What is the most efficient way of removing one element from this array performance wise?**

We are currently using the splice() method, but as I understand this is pretty inefficient since the user almost always removes one of the first 20 elements, causing almost the entire array to be assigned new index values.

Would it be more efficient to reverse the array first, splice, then reverse again? Use the filter() method? Loop through the array with a for/while-loop and create a new array with everything but the excluded element?

Comment: Why don't you measure the various methods you come up with? Also, is this already proving a performance issue? If it's not, don't worry about it.

Comment: it might help to know the type of objects in the array. Is order important? do they have to be in a sequential index (0,1,2,3...) or by a key? Sometimes using an Object is faster because you can simply `delete mydata[key]`.

Comment: I haven't measured performance of the various methods yet because only the production DB have this volumne of entities. I would rather find the theoretically best method before doing a lot of testing on production data. The performance is already kind of an issue since removing an entity produces a 2-3 seconds delay in the UI.

The object type is a custom type that again contains mostly string and int properties, aswell as a datetime. They do not necessarily need to be in a sequential index since the objects contains an ID (int) property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing with dummy data I learned that the splice method uses 1ms on an array of 2000 elements. The problem is how I have implemented Vuex store which caused pretty big delays.